# Texto no se hace negrita

Tags: html5, bootstrap, css3

Estoy escribiendo un parrafo y en la pagina estoy usando Bootstrap 4 y css3, pero al momento de querer hacer una parte del parrafo en negritas no se hace ni con `<b>` ni con `<strong>`

```css
.texto{
margin-top: 30px;
margin-left: 20px;
margin-right: 20px;
color:black;
font-family: 'Roboto', Arial, sans-serif;
}

p{
    color:#222;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid ml-4 pr-5">
  <div class="row">
    <div class=" col-lg-7 " id="contenido-8">
         <div class="texto">
            <h1 class="display-4">NeoBux: Veterana PTC para ganar dinero</h1>
            <hr>
            <p  class="mt-4">
<b>Neobux es la página PTC (Paid To Click o lo que es lo mismo, 
pago por clic) más veterana del sector.</b> 
Bien utilizada y junto a una buena estrategia de referidos alquilados, 
realmente se puede generar grandes beneficios. 
Si estás buscando una página para ganar dinero por Internet a la que dedicar tiempo, 
ésta es sin duda una buena opción para comenzar.</p>
         </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 bg-warning">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
      tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
      quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
      consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
      cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
      proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Las secciones donde pongo `<b>` o `<strong>` no se hace negritas, por que podrá ser?

Comment: No veo donde le dices que quieres usar las negritas, ni un tag <b> html, ni una propiedad css "font-weight: bold;"... No se si entendí el problema.

Comment: En el primer parrafo donde dice Neobux... Ahi lo tengo con la etiqueta b para hacerle negritas  ese pedazo, pero no se hace, nisiquiera ningun texto que coloque las etiquetas strong o b hace su funcion.

Comment: la consola de chrome o firefox que te dice ? tal vez haya un estilo que baje el peso del bold a normal o que la tipografía no soporte bold

Comment: ¿Cómo estás importando la fuente?

Comment: Yo veo que funciona tras hacer la demo con jsfiddle.

Answer (score 2):

Para poner texto en negrita no es poniendo `color:black` si no poniendo en el css, y en la clase en cuestión `text-weight: bold` y ademas te digo, que puede que en otros archivos css, veas el `text-weight` con valores numéricos, que al menos antes de css3 al parecer había diferentes vales de negrita.

(Añadido sobre los valores numericos de `text-weight`)

> Dependiendo del tipo de tipografía, `font-weight` 400, 600, 700, 900 son equivalentes a normal, semi-bold, bold o extra-bold - [alo Malbarez](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/81450/alo-malbarez)
>   (Gracias por esta info, yo nunca he utilizado valores numericos, y lo he visto alguna vez, pero nunca aprecie cambio)

Espero haberte podido ayudar, y para mas información puedes consultar [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com) una pagina que ayuda bastante en estas cositas

Edit: También puedes agregar en html, etiquetas como: `<strong>"Lo que quieras en negrita"</strong>` o `<b>"Lo que quieras en negrita"</b>` por si no quieres todo el texto en negrita por ejemplo y solo ciertas partes.

Comment: Yo se eso, lo de color:black es para colocar el parrafo en color negro, pero cuando utilizo dichas etiquetas <strong> o <b> no hace su funcion, no hace negritas esas partes del parrafo que yo quiero que se hagan

Comment: dependiendo del tipo de tipografía, `font-weight` 400, 600, 700, 900 son equivalentes a `normal`,  `semi-bold`, `bold` o `extra-bold`

Comment: Vale, pues en vez de `<strong>` prueba a añadir un `<span>` y dale al span una clase que solo tenga `text-weight:bold;`

Comment: los cambios en weight no se aprecian si la tipografía no lo soporta, históricamente si la tipografía no tenía equivalente bold los navegadores lo mentían/mienten modificando los vectores de cada letra (en normal), pero es una práctica que va cayendo en desuso pues a veces queda muy feo, teniendo uno que jugar con el text-rendering, font-smoothing o font-spacing.

Comment: Que yo sepa, Roboto si que permite usar negrita, italic y demás versiones. (Si no me confundo porque la use hace tiempo en una práctica)

Comment: depende como la incluyas y si ya existe en el sistema donde la ves por ejemplo para normal y bold `<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700" rel="stylesheet">` 400=normal, 700=bold